# How can i fail Neo4j transaction if validation query fails

Tags: database, neo4j, transactions, cypher

I have a Neo4j transaction that is composed from several cypher queries.

for idempotency sake, i'd like to include a validation query that will fail the transaction if needed.

any idea how can i do that?

i was looking how to return an error or throw exception but it doesn't seem so popular as i cant find anything about it

whats the best practice that is recommended here?

Comment: Do you want to throw an error from cypher ?

Comment: @DanStarns is that the way to do it? if so, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [apoc.util.validate](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.util/apoc.util.validate/) to throw an error from inside cypher.

Example:

```
CALL apoc.util.validate(true, "MY ERROR MESSAGE")
```

Comment: amazing! would that throw an exception/error and fail the transaction ?

Comment: @danfromisrael yeah